# How to run Mockoon environment file on docker

Tags: docker, mocking, dockerfile, mockoon

I have tried to mount local Mockoon environment file on docker container with mockoon-cli:latest image.
It was building successfully but when it had started with in 3 seconds it stopped again and again.
I have follow the steps as mentioned in the given URL

https://mockoon.com/tutorials/run-mock-api-anywhere-cli/

I have also tried with dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN npm install -g @mockoon/cli@3.0.0
COPY mockoon-frontier-mssws-mocks.json ./mockoon-frontier-mssws-mocks.json

# Do not run as root.
RUN adduser --shell /bin/sh --disabled-password --gecos "" mockoon
RUN chown -R mockoon ./mockoon-frontier-mssws-mocks.json
USER mockoon

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["mockoon-cli", "start", "--daemon-off", "--disable-log-to-file", "--data", "mockoon-frontier-mssws-mocks.json", "--container"]

# Usage: docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port> mockoon-test
```

but again facing same issue

I have follow the steps as mentioned in the given URL

https://mockoon.com/tutorials/run-mock-api-anywhere-cli/

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What happens when you run it?  You say the container exits quickly; is there anything in the container logs?

Comment: @DavidMaze I was able to find out the solution. As per the tutorial , on docker command there is no any hostname defined but while saving the file from Mackoon GUI it has hostname in environment file. So that hostname should be overridden when running docker command but its not working in that manner. So after comparing my file with Mockoon dummy file I found that and remove hostname from file and again run same command and its worked for me